# How can I pass values in header and body to GET response from API using HttpWebRequest class in C#?

Tags: c#, api, httpwebrequest, bearer-token

How to pass values to header and PATH PARAMETERS
section to get response from API, using HttpWebRequest class in C#?

> **HEADER**
>   Authorization: Bearer 
>   UserId: user id
>
> **PATH PARAMETERS**
>   recid: record id

**Bellow code is which I have tried..**

```
 HttpWebRequest MetadataRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(metadatarequestUri);
                MetadataRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
                MetadataRequest.Method = "GET";
                MetadataRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                MetadataRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessTokenValue);
var recid = "00482365-91c4-g416d-b8a1-06agfga8bcfe8ee";
var AccessTokenValue = "8a2fyhfgc-43f1-4b9e-b64a-dca79grdgedr75642";
var userId = "ka.san";
var metadatarequestUri="https://webserverdev.demovision.com:8493/demoecmv2/rest/docs/" + recid + "/attachments";
 Stream memStream2 = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                if (formFields != null)
                {
                    foreach (string key in formFields.Keys)
                    {
                        string formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, key, formFields[key]);
                        byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
                        memStream2.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);
                    }
                }
memStream2.Write(endBoundaryBytes, 0, endBoundaryBytes.Length);
                MetadataRequest.ContentLength = memStream2.Length;
                using (Stream requestStream = MetadataRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    memStream2.Position = 0;
                    byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[memStream2.Length];
                    memStream2.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
                    memStream2.Close();
                    requestStream.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
                }
memStream2.Write(endBoundaryBytes, 0, endBoundaryBytes.Length);
                MetadataRequest.ContentLength = memStream2.Length;
                using (Stream requestStream = MetadataRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    memStream2.Position = 0;
                    byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[memStream2.Length];
                    memStream2.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
                    memStream2.Close();
                    requestStream.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
                }
using (var response = MetadataRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    Stream stream2 = response.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);
                    var uploadedFileResponseFromAltusECM = reader2.ReadToEnd();
                    dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(uploadedFileResponseFromAltusECM);
                    recid = obj.messages[0].message;
                }
```

But its not working as expected.

Comment: "*But its not working as expected*" is not a technical description of a problem. It doesn't even describe what you expect, it shows no results, and no errors, no status codes or anything of any use... Maybe you can edit the question, format the code, show whats not working, what you are getting, what you expect and make it easier for people to help you.. ask see [ask]

Comment: @ TheGeneral sorry, i got 400 error.

Comment: @TheGeneral I want to consume API using HttpWebRequest class, but i don't know How to pass header and Path-Parameters values to API.